# IOS - Best practice to handle large number of images (Performance + Size on disk)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, performance, size

My app `UIKit` stores something like 100 `(100x100) jpeg` files, that suppose to be used as "pattern image". the average size for each image is sometimes like `20~40 kb`.

I'm cocos2d-x developer as well. In cocos environment i'm using `plist` to "bound" each image and than cut it via `plist`. This is great performance and size saver, but as far as I know its not possible on `UIKit`.

So my question is this, **Is there a better way to store/pull this images to improve disk capacity and increase performance, other than drag and drop the files into XCode and use it as usual?**

Comment: 100 100x100 images is not that much memory. Assuming all are loaded in, that's (100 * 100 * 100 * 4) bytes of memory when decoded, which is only 4MB. UIKit will handle de-duplication of your resources, as well as caching / freeing them in low memory environments, so I think this just premature optimization.

Comment: Richard is right in that the amount of memory isn't too bad, but if you really needed to, you could make those images into a single sprite and then call upon it using coords. I've used this site before for CSS Sprite making http://spritegen.website-performance.org

Comment: @Cole that is not good for performance on iOS - the gains you get for cache locality are minimal, and as I mentioned before UIKit does some advanced caching techniques to ensure that only images in use stay in memory at any given time. Also, images over 1024x1024 perform very badly on older devices (due to a hardware limit in the texture buffer, the images must be tiled by UIKit).

Comment: @Richard huh, I would have never thought. I just remember using them for buttons in CSS. The more you know!

Comment: @Cole for CSS/web it's a different scenario however. When you're dealing with the web (prior to HTTP/2.0) you would have had to send an individual request for each file that contained an icon, increasing your load time significantly (as the HTTP header handshake is quite latency intense, even more so with TLS), so it was used as an optimization for content delivery, not content rendering.

Comment: Also, do not use images as colorpattern, always use a full single image for backgrounds. If you dont want the app to consume a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[any number] of images is not really a problem on iOS since there are advanced caching systems in place that take care of reuse of the images. Also the rendering system of iOS is quite great so you don't have to worry about it.

While it is certainly possible to program system for sprites, I would not advice you to do it. This method is primarily used in Web Development (because each image has to be served with new request *note [no longer true with HTTP/2](http://qnimate.com/what-is-multiplexing-in-http2/)) and also obviously for game development (because the less bind texture calls you have, the better).

There is one more good example for why not to use sprites - if you are developing Watch application and you want to do animation, you do it through flipboard style images (sequence of images named 1.png - 100.png), and not by using large atlas of images. While it would be guessing as why did they decide to do it that way (my guess would be because of how good it works internally + throughput of the bluetooth), it is obvious that it is also preferred choice of Apple and so we should follow.

For iOS, there are some pitfalls that you should know:

- Any image loaded from the Web should not be loaded on main thread, the same really goes with every image that is not present at the load of the screen (images in UITableViewCell are great example, because you can see mini-freezes if the images are large as you are scrolling through)
- If you have many layers, images with alpha channel != 1 decrease performance heavily (but are often unavoidable)
- Background image created with `UIColor.colorWithPatternImage()` should be used with caution, as this method is considered problematic ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043077/ios-using-a-pattern-image-as-a-background-memory-leak))

Now as for asynchronous loading of the images, I suggest you take a look at following libraries:

- Haneke ([Obj-C](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke), [Swift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift))
- SDWebImage ([Obj-C](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage))

Both of them are great so it is really matter of preference (I like Haneke better), but they allow you to download images on different threads, be it from Web or from your bundle. They also have extensions for UIImageView which allows you to use 1-line function to load all images easily.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply , The memory leak that colorWithPatternImage might create is very useful detail , as well about the side info :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There will be in iOS 9 if that counts ;) It's called On Demand Resources and lets you store content with Apple and download the content when it's needed for a level, etc. It'll be great for game apps and is what they used as an example at WWDC.

Check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/

Comment: Very useful info, thank you for you answer @Drmorgan!